# EEA Family permit for dependent child

Tags: united-kingdom, eu, eu-citizens, indian-citizens

I am an Indian citizen and my age is 25. I'm student and graduated from a reputed university of U.K. I came back to India after completing my degree and a week before my student visa was supposed to expire. Currently I'm living in a rented accommodation in new delhi and I'm financially dependent on my father as I'm still studying.

My father is a EEA national and wishes to travel to U.K.  and I want to travel with him through the EEA family permit. My father has never been to U.K. before and would face a language barrier too.

Could anybody please tell me if it is possible for me to travel to U.K. with him?  I was thinking about using EEA family permit for dependent. I can provide proofs of being financially dependent on my father like bank transactions.

What are the chances of being refused for EEA family permit? Please advise me on this and provide me with some better alternative way.

Comment: This question appears to be about travel rather than expatriation or migration, and is therefore better suited to travel.stackexchange.com.  I have recent experience with the use of the EEA Family Permit for short- term travel, and will gladly answer the question if you ask it there.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it is much appreciated. Actually my father wants to settle in U.K. and I will be staying with him. So we would be migrating there than just traveling for short term. I want to continue my studies there and look for a job then. Please advise me on this.

Comment: What country is you father a national of? Is your father effectively paying your rent? Can you prove this?

Comment: Given your age, they may want a DNA test.

Comment: Be prepared to be tolerant of questions about whether you and your father are married, and whether you have any children together.

Answer (score 1):

"In assessing an application from an EEA national’s direct family member, the entry clearance officer(ECO) should be satisfied that:

- the applicant is the family member of the EEA national (marriage certificate, birth certificate or other evidence of family link)
- ...the EEA national intends to travel to the UK within 6 months and will have a right to reside under the Regulations on arrival, and the non-EEA national will be accompanying or joining the EEA national; and
- the EEA national is residing in the UK in accordance with the EEA Regulations (as qualified person (exercising treaty rights) if more than 3 months) and the non-EEA national is joining them; or 
  .
  .
  .
- if applying as dependent family members (dependent children 21 and over and dependent relatives) they are dependent on the EEA national or the EEA national’s spouse or civil partner;..."

https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/eea-family-permits-eun02/eea-family-permit-eun02#eun29-how-do-i-establish-dependency-under-the-eea-regulations

https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/eligibility

If you can demonstrate your dependent status with certainty, it looks pretty feasible.